# Как реализовать множественное добавление продуктов(услуг) к заказу?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework

Вопрос такой: есть 5 сущностей БД (Order(заказы), Service(услуги), Category(по категориям можно выбирать услуги,исключаем чрезмерность данных), Status(статус заказа), ServiceForOrder(связка order и service)

Создал вьюмодель: OrderViewModel (которая принимает поля из Order и Service). 
Поля:

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        //public OrderModel()
        //{
        //    services=new List<Service>();
        //}
        [Display(Name = "Номер заказа:")]
        public int OrderModelId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Фамилия и имя клиента:")]
        public string NameClient { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Номер телефона клиента:")]
        public string PhoneNumbClient { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Оплаченная сумма клиентом:")]
        public decimal ClientPayForOrder { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Дата создания заказа:")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public DateTime OrderCreateDateTime { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Статус заказа:")]
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Дата изменения заказа:")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]
        public  DateTime OrderLastModifDateTime { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Услуга:")]
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }

        //public virtual  ICollection<Service> services { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Количество:")]
        public int QuantityItem { get; set; }
        public Service Service { get; set; }
    }
```

Сущности:

```
public class Service
    {
        public Service()
        {
            ServiceForOrders = new List<ServiceForOrder>();
        }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public string TitleService { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionService { get; set; }
        public Decimal CostPerService { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ServiceForOrder> ServiceForOrders { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string TypeCategory { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {

        public Order()
        {
            ServiceForOrders = new List<ServiceForOrder>();
        }

        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string NameClient { get; set; }
        public string PhoneClient { get; set; }
        public decimal PayClient { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreateOrder { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateLastModifOrder { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ServiceForOrder> ServiceForOrders { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public string StatusOrder { get; set; }
    }

    public class ServiceForOrder
    {

        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public int QuantityService { get; set; }

        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public Service Service { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Правильно реализована вьюмодель для добавления множества услуг??? И как лучше реализовать добавление: через checkboxы или как-то по-другому? Может есть ссылки на какие-то туториалы или примеры кода?

Comment: подход Code-first

Comment: Вы спрашиваете оценку того, что не показали. Ваше описание ничего не дает - если у вас вопросы по коду, покажите код.

Comment: @tym32167, секунду, сейчас покажу.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/s7h988Up - модель

https://pastebin.com/eXyj5XiF - сущности

логики нет, потому что не знаю как лучше реализовать. Хотел бы может примеры какие-то посмотреть

Comment: Весь необходимый код добавляйте текстом в вопрос. Не надо никаких ссылок в комментариях - никто не будет из читать.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @tym32167, изменил текст вопроса

Comment: Добавление в БД никак не связано с интерфейсом и чекбоксами. Для того, чтобы добавить сервис в существующий заказ, вам надо получить заказ из БД, добавить к заказу нужные сервисы и сохранить изменения.

Comment: @tym32167 вопрос то и заключается как все правильно это обыграть с коллекциями. Я понимаю, что вопрос может сложный и поэтому жду каких рекомендаций по освоении материала, т.е. ссылок на статьи или что-то подобное, где можно подчерпнуть такую реализацию

Comment: У вас вопрос про добавление данных в БД или про то, как это делается на UI?

Comment: Если у вас что то вроде магазина с товарами и заказами и вам надо почитать литературу про asp.net mvc - то я бы порекомендовал книгу Адама Фримана - [Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.apress.com/gb/book/9781430265290) ([исходники](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-mvc-5)), там как раз есть пример с интернет магазином и заказами